# Send vote after click radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, controller, radio-button, thymeleaf

On my website I have a form that allows you to send select a vote and after that the choice of the vote allows you to send (optional) a comment or photo or audio, this button allows you to send everything.

The form of the vote appears after searching for a specific location.

Now I would like to change the functionality, I wish that after clicking on the vote is saved directly right away, and afterwards appear as always the ability to send comments and photos.

This is my form:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".sinButtonVote > img").click(function(e){
 $(this).parents("div.sinWebQuestion").addClass("voteChosen");
 $("#sendVoteButton").removeClass("hidden");
 $("#sendOpinion").removeClass("hidden");
});
  $("div.sinBottomVoteButton").click(function(e){
  $("#sendVoteButton").removeClass("hidden");
});
function afterOpinionSent() {
 $("#wsCompany").val("Select Location").change();
 }
</script>
```

```html
<form th:action="@{/opinion/vote}" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
 data-successHandler="afterOpinionSent"
 class="s_ajaxForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="webLocationId" th:value="${webLocation.id}" th:if="${webLocation!=null}"/>
 <div th:each="webQuestion : ${webQuestions}" class="row WebQuestion">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div th:text="${webQuestion.question}" class="sinButtonVoteLabel">Question?</div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <label th:each="vote : ${ {3, 2, 1, 0} }" class="radio-inline ButtonVote">
    <input type="radio" th:name="|questionVote[${webQuestion.id}]|" th:value="${vote}"/>
    <img yada:src="@{|/res/img/question/${webQuestion.iconName+vote}.png|}" th:alt-title="|Voto ${vote}|">
   </label>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;" id="sendOpinion" class="s_ajaxForm hidden">
  <div style="float: left; width: 35%;" class="BottomVoteButton">
   <label class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#voteComment">
    <img yada:src="@{/res/img/question/comment.png}" title="Comment">
    <span>Opinion</span>
   </label>
   </div>
   <div style="float: left; width: 30%;" class="BottomVoteButton">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
  <img yada:src="@{/res/img/question/photo.png}" height="35px" title="Photo"><br />
  <span>Photo</span>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="hidden" name="photo"> 
  </label> 
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden; width: auto;" class="BottomVoteButton">
   <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    <img yada:src="@{/res/img/question/Audio.png}" title="Audio">
    <span>Audio</span>
    <input type="file" accept="audio/*" capture="microphone" class="hidden" name="audio"> 
   </label>
  </div>
 <div id="voteComment" class="collapse" th:if="${webLocation!=null}">
  <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" maxlength="1024" name="comment" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="sendVoteButton" type="submit" class="s_ajaxForm btn btn-default btn-block hidden">Send</button>
</form>
```

And this is my opinionController.java:

```js
@RequestMapping("/vote") // Ajax
 public String voto(FormOpinioni formOpinioni, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
  WebLocation webLocation = null;
  if (formOpinioni.getWebLocationId() != null) {
   webLocation = webLocationRepository.findOne(formOpinioni.getWebLocationId());
  }
  if (webLocation==null) {
   return "/yada/ajaxError"; 
  }
  
  YadaBrowserId yadaBrowserId = yadaBrowserIdDao.ensureYadaBrowserId(COOKIE_UUIDNAME, COOKIE_EXPIRATIONSEC, request, response);
  
  // Save WebResult
  String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
  for (Map.Entry<Long,String> idAndVote : formOpinioni.getQuestionVote().entrySet()) {
   long questionId = idAndVote.getKey();
   int vote = Integer.parseInt(idAndVote.getValue());
   boolean stored = webResultDao.storeResult(questionId, vote, yadaBrowserId, ipAddress);
  }
  
  // Save il comment
  String commento = formOpinioni.getCommento();
  if (!StringUtils.isBlank(comment) && webLocation.isEnabled()) {
   boolean stored = webAttachmentDao.storeAttachment(WebAttachment.TYPE_COMMENT, comment, ipAddress, webLocation, yadaBrowserId);
  }

  // Save photo
  saveUpload(WebAttachment.TYPE_IMAGE, formOpinioni.getPhoto(), webLocation, yadaBrowserId, ipAddress, response, model);
  
  // Save audio
  saveUpload(WebAttachment.TYPE_AUDIO, formOpinioni.getAudio(), webLocation, yadaBrowserId, ipAddress, response, model);
  
  return thanksForOpinion("Registered opiniono", model);
 }
 
 private String thanksForOpinion(String title, Model model) {
  return YadaNotify.instance(model)
    .yadaOk().yadaAutoclose(2000)
    .yadaTitle(title)
    .yadaMessage("<p style='text-align:center; min-height:60px;'>Thanks You for opinion</p>")
    .yadaSave();
 }
```

How do I change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make following changes

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(".sinButtonVote > img").click(function(e){
    $(this).parents("div.sinWebQuestion").addClass("voteChosen");
    $("#sendVoteButton").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#sendOpinion").removeClass("hidden");
});
  $("div.sinBottomVoteButton").click(function(e){
  $("#sendVoteButton").removeClass("hidden");
});
function afterOpinionSent() {
    $("#wsCompany").val("Select Location").change();
    }
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input[@name='YOUR_RADIO_INPUTNAME']").click(function(){

$("#YOUR_FORM_ID").ajaxSubmit({url: '/vote', type: 'post'});
});
});
</script>
```

Make a Action method which will can process only vote entry .